# importing short description creates additional default value in store_view_code

Tags: magento2, product-import

Magento 2.4.5 p1
When importing, updating the short description it started to create a new duplicate entry with the same entity ID, where the store_view_code duplicate entry is added as default value.

This result to the original product short description remains unchanged. And a new product page view is created with a store_code_view duplicate entry with the value default.

When re-importing the short description updates into the default duplicate store_code_view then the content reflects on the product page.

One thing to note, all the other attributes are not affected, if there was for example also a long description, and i delete it still remains. By default, i do not have the option on the product page, to change views to edit the original default store_view_code which was blank, and newly duplicated generated store_view_code child with the value - default.

I hope this explanation make sense, i attached a snippet of the export after importing the short description as reference.

Its causing major issues in terms of updating the long description, as the only to do it is to delete the entity value of description in the database and recreate it as a side affect of this symptom.

I further notice that to edit the products from within admin, the pages renders terribly slow since this new process took affect.

Any suggestions or guidance here will be very much appreciated.